# Bulk Insert expected performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, oledb, bulkinsert

Currently we're doing some bulk loading using IRowsetFastLoad and we're getting about 50,000 rows per second.  My gut tells me that's low and given the upper bound of the data sizes (around a billion rows), it would be real nice to get that 50K as big as possible.

Does anyone have metrics on what we should expect from IRowsetFastLoad?

As an aside, I'm open to ideas for other methods that would increase performance as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's good performance or not, but you can take steps to improve performance.  First, you want to make sure you're getting the fast-load performance that you want.  Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421.aspx) for some information.